# 2010 Jeep Compass makes a smacking noise under the dash when the fan is turned on

Tags: jeep, hvac, compass

It does not matter if it is heat or ac. My ac compressor quit and I replaced it and had air for one day. Checked the vacuum and the freon all looks great it quit working when the noise started coming from behind the glove box does this have any thing to do with it. And why? Thanks Annette

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind:

1. The cabin air filter is faulty and causing the noise.
2. Something has fallen into the defroster vents and is now causing an issue.

You can probably pull the fan out and take a look, but it will take a little digging to get to it. Something is interfering with it, that's for sure. The bottom of the blower motor looks something like this:

[image]

You can usually get to it from the passenger side foot well. The three screws will take it down, then you can see what is interfering with it.

Comment: It only makes the noise for a short time 30 seconds or so only when you first turn on the fan. It does not matter if it is heat or ac.